# ios remove nil dictionary inside of nsmutablearray

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I have nsmutable array of dictionaries but some of the dictionaries in the array are nil

```
<__NSArrayI 0x20895690> 
(
    {
        sales = "15023.00";
    }
)
,
<__NSArrayI 0x20895600>
(
    <null>
)
,
<__NSArrayI 0x20895610>
(
    <null>
)
```

Any of you knows how can I remove nil objects?
Any of you knows how can I remove nil objects?

Comment: @HotLicks True.. It could be NSNull objects

Comment: how do you remove all the empty arrays?

Comment: @Juan You have no empty arrays.

Comment: Are you perhaps getting these arrays by parsing json?

Comment: That's a strange looking dump.  How did you produce it?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist NP, I deleted the now-obsolescent one too.

Comment: The standard `description` dump of an NSArray wouldn't include the `<__NSArrayI 0x20895690>` elements.

Comment: @HotLicks but `debugDescription` does include it.

Comment: I can get the same output as the OP by doing this (sorry for no line breaks in comments): `[ @[@[@{@"sales":@15023}],@[[NSNull null]],@[[NSNull null]]] debugDescription];`

Comment: @Juan By the way. That isn't an array of dictionaries. It's an array of arrays of dictionaries (or NSNull).

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist - Yeah, I haven't played with debugDescription, it being a relatively new invention.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist Yes is array of dictionaries. Do you know how to remove the null dictionaries?

Comment: @Juan I gave an answer to the question (if you missed it)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a category that caters to a few scenarios. It will remove an empty array, a [NSNull null] object, and an NSArray containing a single [NSNull null] object. It could be customized further if you find the data you are working with has other formats.

```
@interface NSMutableArray (EmptyObjects)
- (NSMutableArray *)so_removeEmptyObjects;
@end

@implementation NSMutableArray (EmptyObjects)

BOOL arrayContainsSingleNullObject(id obj)
{
    return  [obj isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] &&
    [obj count] == 1 &&
    [obj lastObject] == [NSNull null];
}

BOOL objectCountIsZero(id obj)
{
    return ([obj respondsToSelector:@selector(count)] && ([obj count] == 0));
}


- (NSMutableArray *)so_removeEmptyObjects
{
    NSIndexSet *emptyIndexes = [self indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        return arrayContainsSingleNullObject(obj) ||
                objectCountIsZero(obj) ||
                (obj == [NSNull null]);

    }];
    [self removeObjectsAtIndexes:emptyIndexes];
    return self;
}

@end
```

Testing it out:

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [@[ @{@"sales" : @"15023.00"}, @[ [NSNull null] ], [NSNull null], @[] ] mutableCopy];
NSLog(@"%@", mutableArray);
[mutableArray so_removeEmptyObjects];
NSLog(@"%@", mutableArray);
```

Before:

```
(
    {
        sales = "15023.00";
    },
    (
        "<null>"
    ),
    "<null>",
    (
    )
)
```

After:

```
(
    {
        sales = "15023.00";
    }
)
```

Comment: That won't work for the given example because it is an NSNull inside of an array that's inside of the array - the count is therefore one even though the arrays contain only NSNull.

Comment: Updated again with a few scenarios that could be further customized. You're answer is more succinct though.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your output you are dealing with an array of arrays of dictionaries so it's the empty arrays (inner) that you should be filtering out.

```
NSMutableArray *originalData = [@[
                                  @[@{@"sales":@15023}],
                                  @[[NSNull null]],
                                  @[[NSNull null]]
                                 ]  mutableCopy];

NSLog(@"%@", [originalData debugDescription]); // Your original output

// Filter out the empty arrays (and all arrays not containing dictionaries
[originalData filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    if (![evaluatedObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) return NO; // Not an array

    NSArray *array = evaluatedObject;
    if (!array.count) return NO; // Empty

    if (![array[0] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) return NO; // First item is not a dictionary

    return YES; // Everything is fine. Keep this item
}]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a predicate:

```
    NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [@[ @[@{@"sales" : @"15023.00"}], @[[NSNull null]], @[[NSNull null]] ] mutableCopy];

    NSLog(@"Array is: %@", [mutableArray debugDescription]);

    NSPredicate *pred= [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) 
   {
        return ! ( [evaluatedObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] && [evaluatedObject lastObject] == [NSNull null] );
    }];
    [mutableArray filterUsingPredicate:pred];

    NSLog(@"Array is now: %@", [mutableArray debugDescription]);
```

The result:

Pre value:

```
Array is: <__NSArrayM 0xa324130>(
<__NSArrayI 0xa3240b0>(
{
    sales = "15023.00";
}
)
,
<__NSArrayI 0xa3240f0>(
<null>
)
,
<__NSArrayI 0xa324100>(
<null>
)

)
```

---

Post Predicate:

```
Array is now: <__NSArrayM 0xa324130>(
<__NSArrayI 0xa3240b0>(
{
    sales = "15023.00";
}
)

)
```